# Variables always return a value of undefined

Tags: javascript

I apologize if this question is formatted improperly, this is my first post on SO and my first real point of getting stuck.

In the below code, the functions playerChoice and computerChoice are supposed to return a value of either 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors'. But every time I log them in the console, they appear as undefined and I can't compare the two choices. I need these values to continue developing the web page otherwise the code can't do anything to compare the choices. I'll show where I tried manipulating them below (they are marked with ***:)

(I only showed where I tried to put the 'rock' value because scissors and paper were put in the same places.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
// buttons to be manipulated
const newButton = document.getElementById('newGameButton'); 
const rockSelect = document.getElementById('rockPicture');
const paperSelect = document.getElementById('paperPicture');
const scissorSelect = document.getElementById('scissorPicture');

// image or text fields to be manipulated
const playerWeapon = document.getElementById('playerWep');
const compWeapon = document.getElementById('compWep');
const pWepLabel = document.querySelector('.playerWeaponLabel');
const compWepLabel = document.querySelector('.compWeaponLabel');
const roundResult = document.getElementById('roundResult');
const playerScore = document.getElementById('scoreplayer');
const compScore = document.getElementById('scoreComp');
const img = '';
const src = ''; 

// player onclick function

let playerChoice = '';

function playerPlay() {
    
    rockSelect.addEventListener('click', function(){

        *** TRIED PLACING playerChoice = 'rock' HERE, LOGGED UNDEFINED ***

        chooseRock();
        computerPlay();
        if (document.getElementById('imageP')) {
            (document.getElementById('imageP')).remove();
        }
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.className = 'rock';
        img.id = 'imageP';
        img.src = 'images/rock1.png';
        const src = document.getElementById('playerWep');
        src.appendChild(img);

        *** TRIED PLACING playerChoice = 'rock' HERE, LOGGED UNDEFINED ***

     
    })
    paperSelect.addEventListener('click', function(){
        choosePaper();
        computerPlay();
        if (document.getElementById('imageP')) {
            (document.getElementById('imageP')).remove();
        }
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.className = 'paper';
        img.id = 'imageP';
        img.src = 'images/paper1.png';
        const src = document.getElementById('playerWep');
        src.appendChild(img);

        
      
    })
    scissorSelect.addEventListener('click', function(){
        chooseScissors();
        computerPlay();
        if (document.getElementById('imageP')) {
            (document.getElementById('imageP')).remove();
        }
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.className = 'scissors';
        img.id = 'imageP';
        img.src = 'images/scissors1.png';
        const src = document.getElementById('playerWep');
        src.appendChild(img);
        
    })
    
    function chooseRock() {
        pWepLabel.innerHTML = 'Rock';

        *** TRIED PLACING playerChoice = 'rock' HERE, LOGGED UNDEFINED ***
    }
    function choosePaper() {
        pWepLabel.innerHTML = 'Paper';
        
    }
    function chooseScissors() {
        pWepLabel.innerHTML = 'Scissors';
        
    }

    return playerChoice;
    
}
```

Comment: Can you add detail which statement returns undefined, and probably separate that code out. You have a couple of functions and it can get overwhelming.

Comment: When you are doing playerChoice = 'rock' manually, where is it logging undefined?

Comment: It logs undefined in the console. For example, I want when a player clicks on rock to change playerChoice to rock (in the areas marked between *** in the above code. No matter what I do it will not take the value I assign it. @TusharShahi

Comment: playerPlay runs only once and returns the value '' once.  Your event handlers are only reacting to the event. Where are you checking playerChoice again?

Comment: So I tried making a new function called playGame which runs playerPlay(). Then in the chooseRock() function for example I would try setting playerChoice to rock. I want to compare playerChoice with computerChoice but none of them will take a value if I try to change it in the functions. @TusharShahi thank you for replying by the way.

Comment: Runnning chooseRock() will log undefined only because it is not returning anything. put console.log(playerChoice) after changing your playerChoice and tell me what you see. It should log rock.

Comment: **Every** javascript function returns `undefined` unless you explicitly `return` something other.

Comment: Ok. Trying this now.

Comment: So, I've tried making it return playerChoice and still when I log it in the console it is undefined. Here's an example. @TusharShahi                                                                                       function chooseRock(){
        pWepLabel.innerHTML = 'Rock';
        playerChoice = 'rock';
        return playerChoice;
        
    }

Comment: Oh wait, wow thanks. I figured it out. Thank you! @TusharShahi

Answer (score 0):

`chooseRock` and the other choosers should be filling an internal variable to keep track of status. I guess it would be `playerChoice`. So besides showing it in your HTML, also save it to the variable that you choose to keep track of choices.

`computerPlay` function is not defined.

Another suggestion: try to separate your game logic from your presentation.